# Wave equation - use parallelogram rule to solve the problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Given wave equation: $ u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0 $, let u be a solution.

Points A, B, C, D are vertices of parallelogram of two pairs of characteristic lines: $ x-ct=c1, x-ct=c2, x+ct=d1, x+ct=d2 $

Use parallelogram rule to find u that satisfies this:

$ u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0, u(-a,a)=a,$  $ $  $ u(a,a)=a^2 $ for $ a>0 $

Guys, how can I use parallelogram rule here? I know that if we draw the characteristic lines we will get picture like that.
[image: parallelogram based on vertices of characteristic lines]

Answer (score 0):

You are given data on the "angle" $y=-x,\, x\le 0$ and $y=x,\, x\ge 0$. If you take any point $P(x_0,y_0)$ inside this angle (above the given lines) and you draw characteristic lines parallel to the sides of the angle, the value of $u$ there is the sum of the values carried by the characteristics (this is what the general solution of the wave equation is). The intersections with the sides of the angle are $(\frac{x_0+y_0}{2}, \frac{x_0+y_0}{2})$ (characteristic with  slope $-1$) and $(\frac{x_0-y_0}{2}, \frac{y_0-x_0}{2})$ (characteristic with slope $+1$). Then,
$$
u(x_0,y_0)=\frac{y_0-x_0}{2}+\left(\frac{x_0+y_0}{2}\right)^2
$$
The solution is not determined uniquely outside of the angle.

The parallelogram rule just tells you that the sums of the values of the solution at opposite vertices of a parallelogram are equal. In your case the parallelogram is formed by $(x_0,y_0)$, $(0,0)$ and the intersections of the characteristics with the initial angle I mentioned before. You get the same answer of course.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dear GReyes, can you explain how did you find that equation about ?

Comment: The parallelogram rule is a direct consequence of the form of the general solution $u(x,t)=F(x+ct)+G(x-ct)$ of the wave equation $u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}$. If you form a parallelogram in the $(x,t)$-plane with vertices $A,B,C,D$ (say, in that order clockwise) with slopes $+c$ and $-c$, then $u(A)+u(C)=u(B)+u(D)$. This is a straightforward consequence of the fact that $F$ is a constant along two of the opposite sides and $G$ is constant along the other two. You choose your vertices $A(0,0)$, $C(x_0,y_0)$, and $B$ and $D$ are the intersections of the characteristics with your initial angle.